# Rails rake db:create load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-14.04, fedena

I am trying to install [project fedena](http://projectfedena.org/install). I have installed ruby on rails by following [this link](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04). when I run `rake db:create` command, it is throwing following error:

```
rameshpaul@rameshpaul-hp:~/ruby_projects/fedena$ rake db:create 
/home/rameshpaul/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rake:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/rameshpaul/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake (LoadError)
        from /home/rameshpaul/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
rameshpaul@rameshpaul-hp:~/ruby_projects/fedena$
```

Comment: fedana might not work with ruby 2.2, i think you need to work with 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

Run Bundle install and then create the db as Rake generater is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade ruby version to 1.8.7 to use fedena